# Asp.Net Core 3.0 Custom Control Validation is not working

Tags: asp.net-core

I have created a custom dropdown as follows, which we can use the json file as data source. Control is rendering properly, but unobtrussive validations are not working. Kindly help me to identify what I have missed.

My Control

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace MyApp.UserControls
    {
        [HtmlTargetElement("json-select", Attributes = ForAttributeName + "," + ItemsAttributeName + ",class")]
        public class JsonDropdownList : TagHelper
        {
            private const string ForAttributeName = "asp-for";
            private const string ItemsAttributeName = "asp-itemsource";

            [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
            [ViewContext]
            public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

            [HtmlAttributeName(ForAttributeName)]
            public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

            [HtmlAttributeName(ItemsAttributeName)]
            public string ItemSource { get; set; }

            [HtmlAttributeName("class")]
            public string ClassName { get; set; }
            public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
            {
                output.SuppressOutput();
                output.Content.Clear();
                output.Content.AppendHtml(this.GenerateDropDownList(ItemSource));
            }

            private IHtmlContent GenerateDropDownList(string path)
            {
                var items = this.ReadJson(path);
                TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("select");
                tb.MergeAttribute("id", For.Name);
                tb.MergeAttribute("name", For.Name);
                if (For.Metadata.IsRequired)
                {
                    tb.Attributes.Add("data-val", "true");
                    tb.Attributes.Add("required", "required");
                }



                tb.AddCssClass(ClassName);

                tb.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(this.GenerateDropDownListItems());
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    tb.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(this.GenerateDropDownListItems(item));
                }
                return tb;
            }

            private IHtmlContent GenerateDropDownListItems(SelectListItem item = null, bool selected = false)
            {

                TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("option");
                if (item != null)
                {
                    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", item?.Value);
                    tagBuilder.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(item?.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    tagBuilder.InnerHtml.AppendHtml("--select--");
                }
                return tagBuilder;
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ReadJson(string JsonPath)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(JsonPath))
                    {
                        string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        List<SelectListItem> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SelectListItem>>(json);
                        return items;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have used the same in cshtml as follows

```
  <json-select asp-for="Title" asp-itemsource="@ViewBag.TitleJson" class="form-control">
                                </json-select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
```

ViewBag.TitleJson is nothing but my json file path.

my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Text": "Mr",
    "Value": "Mr"
  },
  {
    "Text": "Mrs",
    "Value": "Mrs"
  },
  {
    "Text": "Ms",
    "Value": "Ms"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer as follows

```
        private IHtmlContent GenerateDropDownListItems(SelectListItem item = null, bool selected = false)
        {

            TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("option");
            if (item != null)
            {
                tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", item?.Value);
                tagBuilder.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(item?.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                 tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", string.Empty);
                tagBuilder.InnerHtml.AppendHtml("--select--");
            }
            return tagBuilder;
        }
```